# How to convert time zone from user input? using python

Tags: python, time, timezone, pytz

I need to convert time and time zone from user input to 'America/New_York'
,,,,py

```
import datetime
import pytz
user_inp_time  =input("What is your hour? " )
user_inp_tz   = input("Your time zone is? ") #input Europe/Chisinau

user_time     = datetime.datetime.strptime(user_inp_time,"%H:%M")
user_tz       = pytz.timezone(user_inp_tz)

tz2= ('America/New_York')
ny_time= user_time.astimezone(pytz.timezone(tz2))
print("In Europe/Chisinau is :", user_time)
print("In America/New_York is :", ny_time)
```

I got this error
raise UnknownTimeZoneError(zone)
pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError

Comment: Is the timezone unknown because the correct spelling is Chisinau? You can use `pytz.all_timezones` to get a list of all valid inputs.

Comment: Your code works fine using correct inputs `Europe/Chisinau`.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comment says, provided time zone is not a valid time zone. You can get a list of pytz time zones with `print(pytz.all_timezones)`. You should check if the time zone is valid in your code using

```
if user_inp_tz not in pytz.all_timezones:
    print("Invalid time zone input")
else:
    user_tz       = pytz.timezone(user_inp_tz)
    user_time     = datetime.datetime.now(user_tz)
    ny_time= user_time.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
    print("In your timezone :", user_time)
    print("In America/New_York is :", ny_time)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I need to get time also from user input also, how do I combine time and time zone ?
 user_time     = datetime.datetime.now(user_tz) here I get only current time

Comment: @AndyVerlan see [the pytz documentation](https://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) on how to localize a date/time.